# Maven Error constructing implementation when Building Project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

Whenever I try to build a Maven project I get the following Error:

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be 
resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6:
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-
plugin-2.6.pom: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: 
Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext): 
DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big. -> [Help 1]
```

Trying to `mvn clean` leads to a similar Error.

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not 
transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-
2.5.pom: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, 
provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext): DerInputStream.getLength(): 
lengthTag=109, too big. -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea what could solve the problem?

EDIT:

Netbeans 8.2

JDK 1.8.0_181

Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363

Maven 3.6.3

No Proxy configured -> Also tried in different networks

Issue started happening suddenly after being a way from work for a week
The week before it started every build worked. Suddenly even completely new projects get the error.

CMD line Maven commands also have this error

reinstalling Maven didn't help

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31316682/2312387

Comment: Refer this one. I think it will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316339/how-to-solve-maven-2-6-resource-plugin-dependency

Comment: Sadly, this did not work.

Comment: Please, update your question with more information: [1] Which version(s) of NetBeans? [2] Version of JDK? [3] Version of OS [4] Do you have any proxy configured? [5] If you can describe what actions have you done before the issue happened? [6] It's the first build and clean for the project or it's an error after some successful builds.

Comment: @Dmitry.M i updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem appears because of corrupted or misconfigured Java truststore (cacerts). Here we have an answer where for example it was [corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24994910/5681468).

The maven tries to download the resource plugin, creates https connection, receives SSL server certificate and tries to validate it against the java truststore.

The default truststore locates here `JAVA_HOME->JRE->lib->security->cacerts` [(see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980460/5681468))

I would suggest the following approach:

1. Find out what truststore the maven uses.
2. Download and update your java version. For example from 1.8.0_181 to jdk1.8.0_231 or the latest (or the same version) and change JAVA_HOME and PATH accordingly. If you have a problem with the corrupted truststore it should resolve it.
3. Also, check that you don't have a misconfigured `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12` [parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40647463/5681468) (should be jks).
4. Check the parameter `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore`. It could point to the corrupted trustore. Ether change it or point to the defalut truststore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Updating to jdk1.8.0_221 solved the problem.